# print function does not show output on sublime text 3 console

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have started off with Python today and stuck with a weird problem. I am using Python 3.5.1 and Sublime text 3 and have written a basic hello world program.

`print('Hello World')`

Saved this file with the name python1.py and pressed Ctrl+B to execute it but the only thing that shows up on the console is [Finished in XYZs] which means that the program sucessfully executes but no output shown.

NOTE: I am using Windows 8(If that's important) and Python is installed properly and I can run my programs from CMD with no problems.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solved it,

Press `Ctrl+Shift+B` after which a list pops up, select python from that list and its done. From next time just pressing `Ctrl+B` will work.

'Ctrl+Shift+B' Means "Build this code and then RUN it" instead of simply compile it

Comment: @jose-rodriguez Saw your edit proposal in the queue. You are probably right with your modification, but let Parag Kadam review it and update his answer. Thanks. See suggested edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17393056)

Comment: On mac os x, it is SHIFT-COMMAND-B

Answer (score 1):

press `Shift-Ctrl-B` and select python. That happens because the program only checks if your python program is correctly. The next time just pressing `Ctrl+B`, will work

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> ( next time onwards)

Comment: I am facing the same problem but in my case the console output is totally blank. I don't see anything there.

Comment: On mac os x, it is SHIFT-COMMAND-B

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed set Build System to Python. 
Only it solved for me.

[image]